# Constraints message in validator of play20

Tags: playframework-2.0

I would like to have a different message for a Constraints validator but i am wandering how to do....
example

```
@Constraints.Required
@Constraints.Pattern("\\d{1,6}")
public String thisIsAnInt;
```

I would like something

```
@Constraints.Required
    @Constraints.Pattern(message="ThisismyspecificMessage",value=\\d{1,6}")
    public String thisIsAnInt;
```

For showing it properly using the bootstrap in a form.

It is possible?
thanks a lot

Answer (score 10):

As you wrote, you can use

```
@Constraints.Required(message = "This is field required")
@Constraints.Pattern(value = "\\d{1,6}", message = "This field must contain from 1 to 6 digits")
public String thisIsAnInt;
```