# Play! 2.0 Overwrite "Invalid Value" Message

Tags: java, validation, playframework-2.0, message, ebean

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the i18n message ids for field infos and errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12582812/what-are-the-i18n-message-ids-for-field-infos-and-errors)

Using Annotations like `@Required` on a `@Entity`-class, a message attribute can be set easily. But how to set / overwrite the "Invalid value" message that is shown when a member of type Double is filled with a string on the form?

The `form.errors()`-map contains an error with key "field name" and value "error.invalid", but I can't figure out the correct key to use in the messages file to overwrite the default message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to override labels from the [source messages file](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/resources/messages.default) in your own `messages.xy` files.

Also take a look at the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11263712/overriding-default-i18n-messages-for-play-2-0/11265036#11265036) some time ago there was a problem if file for default language hasn't the lang extension. AFAIK it was fixed after that answer, however it would be cool if you'll check it and confirm the current state in the comment.

Comment: I can confirm that with Play! 2.0, labels must be overridden in a message.xy (message.en or message.de, etc.) file. Putting `error.invalid=My invalid value` inside the default message-file does not work.