# Error.invalid overwritten message in play framework

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.2

I'm working on a java Play Framework 2.2.3 project and i put some constraints on variables like that :

```
@Constraints.Required(message = "Field required")
public float prix;
```

The only problem I have is that I've got an "error.invalid" (because it is a numeric field, otherwise I've an error.required matched with my message) when I don't put a value in the form.

I know that some people had the same issue ([Play! 2.0 Overwrite "Invalid Value" Message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12773009/play-2-0-overwrite-invalid-value-message) ), and by adding the "error.invalid" into a message.xy, it was working. But it's not with me...

So, is there any other way to display a personalized message or an explanation?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the way you display your error message is wrong.

If your app keeps displaying your error key, you should try to add a wrapping @Messages to you error message.

For example :

```
<span class="help-block">@{field.error.map { error => error.message }}</span>
```

become

```
<span class="help-block">@{field.error.map { error => Messages(error.message) }}</span>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :D It helped me a lot, my boss is very proud of me ;)