# How to change language of tips in play 2 framework?

Tags: localization, playframework-2.0

By "tips" I mean `Required` word under the field, in `Form(mapping("city" -> nonEmptyText,`...

I tried to change default locate by Locale.setDefault, changed system and browser locale, modified application.lang.cookie and application.langsm nothing helped.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Overriding default i18n messages for play 2.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11263712/overriding-default-i18n-messages-for-play-2-0)

Comment: this answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11265036/972676 ..