# how to use the play.data.validation.Constraints.Pattern

Tags: playframework-2.0

how to use the play.data.validation.Constraints.Pattern

```
public class User{
     @Email
     private String email;
     //@Pattern("^[\d]$")   ???
     private String name;

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10772095/462285

Answer (score 0):

For regex exspressions like \d \w etc. in java you have to add extra \ 
for example

```
public class User{
     @Pattern("^[\\d]+$") 
     private String name;

     @Pattern("^[0-9]+$") \\ you too can do it that way
     private String name2;
}
```

and you ommit + at end of regex ( if you wonna more than one digit in name field )